# Plotting 3rd axis as a histogram using color in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

My question is:

I have `x` and `y` coordinates, both in `degrees`. They describe the position of the objects in a region. Now I want to plot something like a histogram, in python, like shown in the figure (done in MATLAB) below [image]

using color codes. It tells how many objects are present over the area. The bin size is `0.5 * 0.5 deg^2`.  So how can I ?

Secondly, how shall I proceed if I have to plot a third axis instead of just the histogram that describes a different parameter altogether, like some number. I mean just three axes : `x, y, z` , z being shown in color-code.

*Thirdly,*

(other questions may be solved after browsing examples shown in comments, but) **how to get the data of the color-histogram? To be clear enough, every bin has a particular value, so that it has been shown in the color-bar. But, how can I get the value of each bin and the corresponding points in the form of array I guess, or whatever suitable form may be available?**

Comment: take a look at these: http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/layer_images.html and http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/hexbin_demo.html

Comment: ok. but having problem with setting the bin-size. They are hexagonal. How to change them? and how to decide which colors signify which number? It's gotta do with cmap. Dunno how to do it..almost got what i needed.thnx for that!